# Retrieving Email with PHP in Batches

Tags: php, imap

I am trying to fetch emails through my mailbox using IMAP class of PHP. Because, the number of messages are in thousands the script is taking too long to execute.

Is there a way I can retrieve messages in batches of say 100 messages each.

Also, how can I uniquely Identify the message. is it ***message_id*** or ***UID*** ? in **imap_fetch_overview()**

```
/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');

/* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
if($emails) {

    /* begin output var */
    $output = '';

    /* put the newest emails on top */
    rsort($emails);

    /* for every email... */
    foreach($emails as $email_number) {

        /* get information specific to this email */
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
        $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);

        /* output the email header information */
        $output.= '<div class="toggler '.($overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread').'">';
        $output.= '<span class="subject">'.$overview[0]->subject.'</span> ';
        $output.= '<span class="from">'.$overview[0]->from.'</span>';
        $output.= '<span class="date">on '.$overview[0]->date.'</span>';
        $output.= '</div>';

        /* output the email body */
        $output.= '<div class="body">'.$message.'</div>';
    }

    echo $output;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you fetch these messages?

Comment: @klennepette I am following this davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap

Comment: Okay, could you still post the code though, it really helps. Also Is it the imap_search() that's slow or is it going through the for loop afterwards?

Comment: @klennepette Its the same code. I am just experimenting with this stuff right now.

Answer (score 0):

First, I believe the  `message_id` is the unique identifier for a message, the `UID` is only unique in the mailbox.

As for the performance. My best guess would be that the for loop is the slow one. The for loop fetches for your thousands of mails the entire mail body.
You could limit your `imap_search` to use `ON <date>` or `UNSEEN`, see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-search.php) for more info what you can use there.

Or you can rewrite the loop so you only handle 100 messages at a time using a regular for loop.